# Adding cross fade between concatenated videos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm using the following command to concat multiple videos together:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -f lavfi -t 0.1 -i anullsrc -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; [1:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; [2:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]; [v0][3:a][v1][3:a][v2][3:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -movflags +faststart output3.mp4
```

How can I modify my command so that I can include cross fade transition between each video? Notice I need a constant duration of fade between all the videos, no need special effect between two videos.
Also I don't care about audio, only care about the transitions between videos.

Is there a generic way that I don't need to specify the exact time when to start the next transition? Like saying between each video do cross fade transition.

Comment: Since you don't have any audio stream, just replace the last chain with `[v0][v1][v2]xfade[v]`.  [See the doc for the `xfade` options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xfade). Drop `-map [a]` and other audio related output options.

Comment: @kesh what do you mean by replacing the last chian? can you please include the full command just to be sure I understand it?

Comment: use `xfade` instead of `concat` (filter chains are segments of a filtergraph separated by semicolons)

Comment: @kesh I get an error: Too many inputs specified for the "xfade" filter.

Comment: oops, forgot that `xfade` only does 1 transition. You need cascade them like shown in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex 
  "[0:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v0]; 
   [1:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v1]; 
   [2:v]scale=3840:2160:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=3840:2160:-1:-1,setsar=1,fps=30,format=yuv420p[v2]; 
   [v0][v1]xfade[v01];
   [v01][v2]xfade[v]" 
   -map "[v]" -c:v libx264 -movflags +faststart output3.mp4
```